# How to apply the :empty selector to an XML document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a XML document that I am trying to select every node that has no child. I thought I could accomplish this with something like:

```
$(XML).find(':empty')
```

However, this just returns and empty set. Here is a quick glimpse at my XML document.

```
<BOM>
  <BOMHeader>
    <ID>ID Text</ID>
    <Classification>ClassificationText</Classification>
    <Version>VersionText</Version>
    <MakeEffectiveDate>MakeEffectiveDateText</MakeEffectiveDate>
    <ExpirationDate>ExpirationDate Text</ExpirationDate>    
    <MaterialID>Material ID Text</MaterialID>
    <MaterialDescription>Material Description</MaterialDescription>
    <Quantity>Quantity Text</Quantity>
    <UOM>UOM Text</UOM>
    <CustomProperties>
      <Example>Example Text</Example>
    </CustomProperties>
  </BOMHeader>
</BOM>
```

So want I need is to be able to read in this XML and just return the set of nodes equal to ID, Classification, Version, MakeEffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, MaterialID, Material Description, Quantity, UOM, and Example.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: None of those elements are `:empty`. Try `:not(:has(*))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` method:

```
var $bachelors = $(XML).find('*').filter(function() {
                   return $(this).children().length === 0
                 })
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Worked liked a charm. I never would have thought of applying the all selector to change it from a #document object. That makes sense. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because none of those elements are `:empty`. `:empty` means element that has no child nodes, such as `<elem></elem>`. Try `:not(:has(*))`:

```
$(XML).find(":not(:has(*))")
```